# In The Matrix franchise, why does Neo always choose to go left?

Tags: the-matrix

In the first movie, Neo chooses the red pill, which is on his left. He's also instructed to go left by Morpheus and Tank. In Reloaded, he chooses to go through the door on his left. Additionally, in Revolutions, from the camera's perspective, Neo runs in the left direction in the subway station.

Comment: He actually chooses to go right when instructed by Tank and then is told 'No, your other left'.

Comment: Interesting observation. I don't *recall* any scene/commentary/interview touching on this, but it isn't something I was on the lookout for. The answer I can imagine (but not write at the moment) entails rewatching the trilogy to verify that Neo's left/right choices are this consistent (especially relative to other characters), and surveying a few other Wachowski projects to see if this is a recurring thing...

Answer (score 2):

What an interesting question! I can only conjecture why the *director* of a movie would choose the left side, but if the choice were left to the actor, then it may be significant that [Keanu Reeves is lefthanded](https://www.cbsnews.com/pictures/famous-lefties/24/). And people [tend to turn in the direction that their handedness favors](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.1028.8696&rep=rep1&type=pdf). On the other hand, Reeves' character, Neo, is supposed to be [righthanded](https://www.cbsnews.com/pictures/famous-lefties/24/).

Answer (score 0):

My best guess would be that, were it intentional (and it probably was) that left handed (or path) is seen as more non-traditional.

90% of humans are right handed. It could be the directors way of suggesting this group typically think differently than the rest of the population (a sentiment fully enforces throughout the series).